# About a sequence related with the complete elliptic integral of the second kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

When answering [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177662/how-do-i-calculate-the-triple-integral-int-02-pi-int-01-int-01-xy-sqrt/1177743#1177743) I proved that if we define $B(\lambda)$ as:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} B(\lambda)&=&\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\lambda^2+1-2\lambda\cos\theta}\,d\theta=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{(2n-1)\,4^n}\right)^2\lambda^{2n}\\&=&\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};1;\lambda^2\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \lambda\,B(\lambda)\,d\lambda = \frac{16}{9\pi} $$
since $B(\lambda)$ satisfies the ODE:
$$ \lambda\, B = (\lambda^2+1)B'+(\lambda-\lambda^3)B''.$$
With the same technique it is not difficult to prove that, if we define $A_k$ as:

> $$ A_k = \int_{0}^{1}x^{2k+1}\,B(x)\,dx $$

we have $A_0=\frac{16}{9\pi}$ and:

> $$ (2k+3)^2\,A_k = \frac{16}{\pi}+(2k)^2\,A_{k-1}. \tag{0}$$

Now the question. **Is it possible to give a nice closed form to $A_k$, given $(0)$?**

$A_k$ appears to be related with a partial sum of the series converging to the Catalan constant, namely: $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)^2}.$$

From the recurrence relation it follows that:
$$ A_k = \frac{16}{\pi(2k+3)^2}+\frac{16}{\pi}\left(\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+3)!!}\right)^2\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left(\frac{(2k+3-2j)!!}{(2k-2j)!!}\right)^2$$
or:
$$ A_k = \frac{16}{\pi(2k+3)^2}+\frac{16}{\pi}\left(\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+3)!!}\right)^2\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left(\frac{(2j+1)!}{2^{2j-1}(j-1)! j!}\right)^2.$$
**Update:** By robjohn's argument shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181357/can-the-following-triple-integral-be-computed-via-elementary-calculus-methods?lq=1), we also have:
$$ A_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{-\cos\theta}^{\cos\theta}(\rho+\cos\theta)^2(\rho^2+\sin^2\theta)^k\,d\rho\,d\theta$$
or:
$$ A_k = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\cos\theta}(\rho^2+\cos^2\theta)(\rho^2+\sin^2\theta)^k\,d\rho\,d\theta.$$