Value of $\int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\sqrt{r_1^2-2r_1r_2\cos(\theta)+r_2^2}\,\mathrm d\theta$ when $r_1\neq r_2$
Whilst solving a problem about average distance between two points in the unit disc the following integral showed up:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\sqrt{r_1^2-2r_1r_2\cos(\theta)+r_2^2}\,\mathrm d\theta$$
I won't make this question too lengthy but I'll try to somehow guide you through how I attempted to solve it and I want to know if the final result (if correct) can be simplified further.
Well, what I did was basically set $z=e^{i\theta}$ with $\mathrm{Arg}(z)=[0,2\pi)$ which yields
$$\oint_{|z|=1}\!\!\sqrt{\dfrac{-r_1r_2z^2+(r_1^2+r_2^2)z-r_1r_2}{z}}\,\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{iz}$$
Note that the polynomial in the numerator has roots $z_1=\dfrac{r_1}{r_2}$ and $z_2=\dfrac{r_2}{r_1}$ and so the integral can be expressed as
$$\oint_{|z|=1}\!\!\sqrt{\dfrac{-r_1r_2(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}{z}}\,\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{iz}$$
Furthermore, notice that there are $3$ possible situations concerning its roots since one is the inverse of the other: if $r_1>r_2$ then $z_1>1$ and $z_2<1$, if $r_1<r_2$ it is the opposite case, and when $r_1=r_2$ both roots are $1$ (but we'll omit this case in this question). This means that $\min=\min(z_1,z_2)<1$ and $\max=\max(z_1,z_2)>1$ when $r_1\neq r_2$. Since the main branch points are $z=0$, $z=\min$ and $z=\max$ we can choose the branch cut $[0,\min]\cup[\max,\infty)$ which allows us to expand the integrand as a Laurent series that's valid for $\min<|z|<\max$, namely, the series will be analytic on the contour. All that said, the integral can be expressed as
$$\oint_{|z|=1}\!\!\sqrt{r_1r_2\max\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{\min}{z}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{z}{\max}\right)}\,\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{iz}$$
Having chosen that branch cut, $\mathrm{Arg}(z-\max)=[0,2\pi)$, $\mathrm{Arg}(z-\min)=[-\pi,\pi)$ and $\mathrm{Arg}(1-\frac{\min}{z})=\mathrm{Arg}(z-\min)-\mathrm{Arg}(z)=[0,2\pi)$ so we can separate the square root into the product of square roots taking into account that principal branch:
$$\sqrt{r_1r_2\max}\oint_{|z|=1}\!\!\sqrt{1-\dfrac{\min}{z}}\sqrt{1-\dfrac{z}{\max}}\,\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{iz}$$
Now it remains to do the binomial expansion of each square root:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{r_1r_2\max}\oint_{|z|=1}\!\!\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2}\choose k}(-1)^k\dfrac{{\min}^k}{z^k}\right)\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2}\choose \ell}(-1)^\ell\dfrac{z^\ell}{{\max}^\ell}\right)\,\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{iz}\\
&=\sqrt{r_1r_2\max}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2}\choose k}{\frac{1}{2}\choose \ell}(-1)^{k+\ell}\dfrac{{\min}^k}{{\max}^\ell}\oint_{|z|=1}\!\!z^{\ell-k-1}\,\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{i}
\end{aligned}$$
Only the $k=\ell$ terms will contribute $2\pi i$ so we're left with
$$2\pi\sqrt{r_1r_2\max}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2}\choose k}^2\left(\dfrac{{\min}}{{\max}}\right)^k$$
Finally, since $z_1=\dfrac{1}{z_2}$, $\max=\dfrac{1}{\min}$ too and so we end up with
$$2\pi\sqrt{r_1r_2\max}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2}\choose k}^2{\min}^{2k}$$
If all of this is correct up until now, is there any way to simplify this summation?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180084/about-a-sequence-related-with-the-complete-elliptic-integral-of-the-second-kind?noredirect=1 May help you!
