# Can the following triple integral be computed via elementary calculus methods?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Consider the following triple integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \int_0^1 xy\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 -2xy\cos(\theta)} \, dx \, dy \,  d\theta$$

A solution was provided to this integral by Jack D'Aurizio [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177662/how-do-i-calculate-the-triple-integral-int-02-pi-int-01-int-01-xy-sqrt), but both his solutions required rather sophisticated methods, like elliptic integrals and special function expansions. What I've been struggling with-and would like a second opinion on-is whether or not this integral can be solved in closed form using very simple calculus techniques,like a standard change of variables to plane polar in the xy domain or spherical coordinates in $R^3$.

My labor over the last 2 days,multiple false starts and geometric arguments in the domain seem to indicate that the answer is no because there's no way to set up the integral without introducing a term of $\sqrt {\sin (ax)}$ or $\sqrt {\cos(ax)}$ at some point. Therefore, some special functional substitution or numerical method solution is needed.

Or am I wrong?

Comment: You probably noticed that yourself, but the argument of the square root very much looks like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines. Maybe this could be helpful for some geometric argument.

Comment: I am really interested in elementary answers. By the way, a suggestion may be to give $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}t\sqrt{1+t^2-2t\cos\theta}\,dt\,d\theta$$ to integrate, that is just a *double* integral leading to exactly the same problem.

Comment: @PhoemueX I saw that,but not how to use it to simplify the problem. Unless you just want to do a naked substitution of c for the whole kit and kaboodle and I don't see how that gets us anything simpler that makes sense. I'll have to go through it carefully,thanks for the hint!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Now THAT is a great idea,I never thought of it! The brilliance of this substitution is that it leaves the limits of integration unchanged! I'll try both suggestions and see which one gives a simpler solution-if any.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^1xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xy\cos(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{1}\\
&=2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^yxy\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xy\cos(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{2}\\
&=2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^1ry^2\sqrt{r^2y^2+y^2-2ry^2\cos(\theta)}\,\,y\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{3}\\
&=2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^1ry^4\sqrt{r^2+1-2r\cos(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{4}\\
&=\frac25\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\sqrt{r^2+1-2r\cos(\theta)}\,r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{5}\\
&=\frac25\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos(\theta)}r^2\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{6}\\
&=\frac2{15}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}8\cos^3(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{7}\\
&=\frac{16}{15}\int_{-1}^1(1-u^2)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{8}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{64}{45}\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: the integral is the same for $x\lt y$ as for $x\gt y$, so assume $x\lt y$ and multiply by $2$
$(3)$: substitute $r=\frac xy$
$(4)$: collect the $y$s and switch the order of integration
$(5)$: integrate in $y$
$(6)$: $(5)$ is the distance from $(1,0)$ integrated over the unit disk centered at $(0,0)$;
$\hphantom{(6):}$this is the same as $r$ integrated over the unit disk centered at $(1,0)$,
$\hphantom{(6):}$whose equation is $r\le2\cos(\theta)$ for $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$
$(7)$: integrate in $r$
$(8)$: substitute $u=\sin(\theta)$
$(9)$: integrate in $u$

Comment: +1 EXCELLENT computation-I was looking to use standard coordinate systems like plane polar for the xy-region or spherical for the entire region using $\theta$ for the vertical angle above the xy plane generated by cos($\theta$). It didn't occur to me to use polar coordinates in a more unorthodox manner-I should have.Any alternative solutions to this problem?

Comment: Looking over my own computations, I just realized I got as far as your equation (5) before getting stuck. : (

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: I was going down the wrong path after $(5)$ until I took a walk with my dog, and realized while we were out that centering the integration on $(1,0)$ would simplify things greatly.

Comment: See,that's the difference between someone who merely understands basic techniques and someone with a truly open mind and who's able to see the unorthodox facts that supply the key to a problem. Even the best mathematicians might not be able to see the relevance of that geometric fact,even though of course they understand what you did once you did it. I smacked my head and did a Homer Simpson once I understood what you did. Which once again demonstrates what too many of us forget once we begin rigorous math: WHENEVER POSSIBLE,DRAW A PICTURE.

Comment: (+1), but this answer deserves much more. $(5)\to(6)$ is the definitive trick, maybe it answers to a recent question of mine, too. Bravo, @robjohn.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: I totally agree with you. Robjohn's solution almost crushed me when I thought that I used a differential equation for a complete elliptic integral to prove his $(9)$. Shame on me.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: The nice thing about the more complex methods is that they might work, even when you can't find trickier methods.